# WCF/SOAP: Move XML namespace definition to parent element

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap

I use WCF to implement a client for a SOAP web service. The code is generated by "Add Service Reference" based on the WSDL file.

The elements of the SOAP request are defined in different namespaces.
Now, a sample message looks like this:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <myMethod xmlns="http://example.org/xsd/requests">
         <RequestData>
            <Foo xmlns="http://example.org/xsd/elements">some</Foo>
            <Bar xmlns="http://example.org/xsd/elements">thing</Bar>
            <Baz xmlns="http://example.org/xsd/elements">content</Baz>
            <!-- .... more elements .... --> 
         </RequestData>
      </myMethod>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

which contains the redundant definition of the *elements* namespace. In order to reduce message size, I would prefer to have the namespace definitions at the top of the message, eg. like this:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:a="http://example.org/xsd/requests" 
           xmlns:b="http://example.org/xsd/elements">
      <a:myMethod>
         <a:RequestData>
            <b:Foo>some</b:Foo>
            <b:Bar>thing</b:Bar>
            <b:Baz>content</b:Baz>
            <!-- .... more elements .... --> 
         </a:RequestData>
      </a:myMethod>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

(I don't really care *which* parent element defines the namespaces, so any way to move the namespace definitions to `Envelope`, `Body` or `MyMethod` would be okay for me.)

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:** removed local `xmlns` definitions in second example (copy-paste mistake ;) )